# Android game crash while Authenticate() in Unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services, google-play-games

I am trying to add GooglePlayGames Services to my android game I am currently developing in Unity 5.3.1f1.

After following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Ae8GeRmdH0) on youtube and downloading the latest [PlayGames-PlugIn](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity), my game always crashes while `Social.localUser.Authenticate(success => { });`.

Any idea what could cause this?

full code of my `DRPlayGames.cs`:

```
using GooglePlayGames;
using GooglePlayGames.BasicApi;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms;

public class DRPlayGames {

    public static void SignIn()
    {
        PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder().Build();
        PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(config);
        PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();

        Social.localUser.Authenticate(success => { });
    }

    #region Achievements
    public static void UnlockAchievement(string id)
    {
        Social.ReportProgress(id, 100, succes => { });
    }

    public static void ShowAchievementsUI()
    {
        Social.ShowAchievementsUI();
    }
    #endregion /Achievements

    #region Leaderboards
    public static void AddScoreToLeaderboard(string id, long score)
    {
        Social.ReportScore(score, id, success => { });
    }
    public static void ShowLeaderboardUI()
    {
        Social.ShowLeaderboardUI();
    }
    #endregion /Leaderboards
}
```

The `SignIn()` methode gets called in my `GameManager.cs` when clicking on the GooglePlay Button:

```
if(m_Hit.transform.tag == "GooglePlayLogIn")
{
    DRPlayGames.SignIn();
}
```

I set up the Android Configuration by copying the resources from my Developer Console and generating the `GPGSIds.cs` file.

I checked and updated every SDK that is needed, but missing/outdated SDKs should cause errors while building, not while playing, or?

Anyone has an idea?

I can provide more code, if needed.

**Edit: The problem was a missing metadata tag. Make sure, you always check the manifest and add important things. Unity doesnt always generate everything you need in there!**

Comment: Do you have an error? An exception or a stacktrace? `I checked and updated every SDK that is needed, but missing/outdated SDKs should cause errors while building, not while playing, or?`: if you are lucky ;-)

Comment: @Stefan thanks for the answer. Thats one of the problem, the Unity Console only works for the Editor itself. But you just reminded me I could simply use the ADM from Android Studio. It said that the metadata-tag with the app id is missing. So I was able to fix it now, and it seems to work! :)